# very simple preg_replace doesnt work

Tags: php, regex

I have this code, is working in all the tester I'm using for regex, but later, in my real php code it doesn't work. What I want is to replace the number in the link for something else

```
     $value='/something.html?helperid=252';
     //patern
     $patternHelperId='/(?<=helperid=)\d{1,}/';
     //replace
     preg_replace($patternHelperId, "mynewreplacement",  $value);

     //debug
     echo "\n$value\n";//  /something.html?helperid=252????? aggain???
```

What's wrong??

Comment: What makes you think it's the RegEx's fault?

Answer (score 2):

You should assign the result of `preg_replace` back to `$value`, like this:

```
$value = preg_replace($patternHelperId, "mynewreplacement",  $value);
```

And, as a sidenote, `\d{1,}` can be replaced with `\d+`.

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace` returns the result. It does not modify the variable in-place

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to take the result of the *preg_replace* function:

```
$newValue = preg_replace($patternHelperId, "mynewreplacement",  $value);

echo "\n$newvalue\n";
```

A better pattern:

```
$patternHelperId='/helperid=\K\d++/';
```